# Is there a way to disable all internet access while having ssh open on a docker container

Tags: networking, ssh, docker, containers, alpine

The end goal is very simple. Open up SSH port 22, but disable internet: I can ssh into the docker container, but I can't do anything that requires an internet connection (download packages, curls commands...)
I have an app which basically allows users to communicate with a docker container running on my server, all from their browser. Until now, I have used a Go server to forward commands to the container via docker exec container commands..., but found it very troublesome to display the outputs (especially if they run something like nano or vim). If anyone has an idea of how to resolve those issues, that would also be helpful. But, let's get back to the main problem.

I have decided to just open ssh on my containers and communicate with them that way. It is very important that the containers don't have any internet access whatsoever. I don't want them to download any packages or send any requests because of obvious DDOS farm threats and similar security problems. Also, it would be preferable if they had root access.

I tried enabling SSH on the containers and then mapping the container's port 22 to the hosts machine. The problem with that is that if I run the container with the network set to 'none' or to 'internal', you cannot map ports. So that's off. Another approach that I tried was setting up iptables rules (using the dockerfile and the entrypoint script) and then removing the "NET_ADMIN" privileges (so they cannot revert the rules I have set up), but you cannot do that because you need NET_ADMIN to configure iptables rules in the first place (weird situation since I build the image before I run the container without NET_ADMIN).

Another possible solution would be too implement iptables on the host machine. However, there will also be a paid version of the VM which has internet access.